# Can't get Raspberry Pi to Control LED Lights

Tags: gpio, led, breadboard

I am currently trying to get my Raspberry Pi to be able to control my RGB LED Strip. Here is the guide I am using: https://popoklopsi.github.io/RaspberryPi-LedStrip/#/. Currently, the LED Strip lights up all colors (Blue, Green, Red), and the Raspberry Pi can control the Red color and the Blue color. However, it cannot control the green color for some reason.

I have the same setup as the guide where GPIO17 is red, GPIO22 is green, and GPIO24 is blue. Even if I switch it to GPIO24 is green and GPIO22 is blue, I still can't control green, and I can control blue perfectly fine.

Where should I start debugging this?

EDIT: I am using PigPIO to control the color of the LED Strip. Since GPIO17 is red, I can enter a command into the pi like `pigs p 17 0` to turn off the red color from the strip completely (to leave only blue and green, creating a blue green color for the entire strip).

Whenever I do `pigs p 22 0` and GPIO22 is connected to green, the green color does not decrease (the result should be that only blue exists, assuming blue is set to 255).

Comment: What do you mean "I can't control greeen"? No green at all or only on/off status (no dimming)?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your led strip is broken or the mosfet is in short circuit.
You said:

> "Even if I switch it to GPIO24 is green and GPIO22 is blue, I still can't control green, and I can control blue perfectly fine.".

This means that the GPIO22 works, and also the library.
Try to swap a working mosfet (i.e., the red) with the green mosfet and see what's happens.